# A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type email to be controlled

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new in react-native, I already display the value from my database to the browser, my question is why the `TextInput` cant edit? and i receive this error

```
 import {
    TextInput,
    SafeAreaView,
  } from 'react-native';


  const [ UserData, setUserData] = useState({});
  const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState('');

  <Formik
      initialValues={{ 
        Email: vEmail, 
       }}
       onSubmit={(values) =>{ console.log("submit"); submitForm(values)}}
    >
  {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, errors, isValid,touched,setFieldValue }) => (

<SafeAreaView>
   <View style={formStyles.SectionStyle}>
      <TextInput
        name="Email"
        value={UserData.Email}
        style={formStyles.inputStyle}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
    </View>
    {(errors.Email && touched.Email) && <Text style={formStyles.errorText}>{errors.Email}</Text> }
 </SafeAreaView>
```

result

[image]

ERROR from my console.logs

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issue

`UserData.Email` is undefined on the initial render, so changing the `value` prop to a defined value will cause this warining.

```
const [ UserData, setUserData] = useState({});

...

<TextInput
  name="Email"
  value={UserData.Email} // <-- undefined
  style={formStyles.inputStyle}
  onChangeText={onChangeText}
/>
```

## Solution

Provide a defined value.

```
const [ UserData, setUserData] = useState({});

...

<TextInput
  name="Email"
  value={UserData.Email || ''} // <-- provide fallback value
  style={formStyles.inputStyle}
  onChangeText={onChangeText}
/>
```

Or provide valid defined initial state.

```
const [ UserData, setUserData] = useState({ Email: '' });

...

<TextInput
  name="Email"
  value={UserData.Email}
  style={formStyles.inputStyle}
  onChangeText={onChangeText}
/>
```

Comment: Good day, how come the `UserData.Email` is undefined? where i can posted my email to the textinput?

Comment: @user14823468 The initial `UserData` state value is an empty object (`{}`), so `UserData.<anyProperty>` will be undefined until you define those properties. Perhaps you meant to use the form values, i.e. `value={values.Email}`? In this case you need to ensure `vEmail` is a defined value or you'll likely see the same warning.

Comment: @user14823468 You can't edit the input because `onChangeText` callback doesn't update the `UserData` state. You've two chunks of state and the Formik form's "state" bag. Which do you want to be your source of truth? I've answered your main on-topic question regarding uncontrolled vs controlled warning, these appear to be extracurricular issues.